# Move objects into std::map c++

Tags: c++, move-semantics, stdmap

I have a tree-like structure

```
class Directory
     {
     public:
         void merge(Directory&& dir);

     private:
         std::map<Key, Directory> directories;
     };
```

merge shall move each subdirectory in dir into directories. Can this be done without copying all Keys and directories?

I have tried to say

```
auto i=dir.begin();
while(i!=dir.end())
    {
    directories.insert(std::move(*i));
    ++i;
    }
```

On non-copyable type Key, this fails with deleted copy ctor error for Key. Would emplace solve the problem? If so, how can I use a workaround for gcc older than 4.8 which does not support that method?

EDIT: I have found that the key returned by the iterator is const, and I should not change the key because that will make look-up:s fail. *But*, I will *not* need the key anymore so now I wonder if it in this case is it safe to typecast to non-const first.

[Compiling example with typecast](http://ideone.com/fbmeRL)

[Non-compiling example without typecast](http://ideone.com/ieYu55)

Comment: are you sure that you don't need a graph ?

Comment: In your example, you are looping over the map you are trying to populate.  You should loop over the files in `dir` and add them to `directories` instead.

Comment: @user245710 No. How can I implement a graph? I realize that I should know more about data structures.

Comment: Is your `Key` move-copyable and move-assignable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do the following instead:

```
  while(i!=dir.directories.end()) {
    directories.insert(std::move(*i));
    ++i;
  }
```

As it is, you are looping over the entries in your current `directories` map, which is probably empty.  This will loop over the directories in `dir` instead and copy each into your local map.

EDIT: Saw your reply.  I got this to compile:

```
class Directory {
public:
  void merge(Directory& dir) {
    std::map<Key, Directory>::iterator i=dir.directories.begin();
    while(i!=dir.directories.end()) {
      directories.insert(std::move(*i));
      ++i;
    }
  }

private:
  std::map<Key, Directory> directories;
};
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: It doesn't if Key has deleted copy constructor.

Comment: So if Key doesn't have a copy constructor, move fails? I think then that you are stuck copying each Key.  Insertion likely makes a copy of they key, so you can't use the reference to it after the move because it is probably destroyed by move.